# How to install ATI graphics card drivers?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, internet, websites

AMD 's website is not opening.So how shall I install my ATI graphics card driver?

Answer (score 0):

Press the super key (the one next to alt) and type "additional drivers", press enter.
Let me know if you find any drivers there. There are some other ways you could try if that doesn't work.